# Run-time error while running VBA code for moving overlapping chart data labels

Tags: excel, vba

Referring to Chris Nielsen's answer in this link:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770429/excel-macro-to-fix-overlapping-data-labels-in-line-chart)

I'm totally a novice in VBA coding. Just searching for a solution for moving overlapping data labels for my work which could save me a huge amount of time.

But when running the 1st code i.e. MovingLabels() a problem occurs in the following line.

```
Set ch = sh.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
```

Would really appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you have object named "Chart 1" in your sheet? If you use non-English version of Excel, this name can be in your language and you have to change it in code. 2. Did you changed anything in code from linked question? If so, can you provide it?

Comment: @EganWolf Wolf thanks very much for your response. Really appreciate it.

1. Yes, i'm sure I have an object named "Chart 1" in the sheet.
2. No, I changed nothing of the codes.

Comment: I have tried running the codes in another workbook. Now there's no error in that line. But after running the macro nothing happens to the overlapping data labels.

Comment: You can debug your code by opening VBA editor, putting text cursor somewhere within the code and pressing F8 to run it line by line (more info in [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting#t=201707261141084903658)). It should let you find out what is wrong.

Comment: @EganWolf thanks again. Tried pressing F8 and now it shows error in the following three lines.  

    Sub MoveLabels()  
  
    Set sh = ActiveSheet  
  
    Set ch = sh.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

Comment: Are you aware that linked answer doesn't change anything if just copied and run? You need to implement some strategy to move labels for every `' Overlap!` comment.

Comment: Did you check if sheet under `sh` variable is a proper sheet? It takes `ActiveSheet`, that means the sheet that is visible in your Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Set ch = activesheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
```

It should work. It refers the first chart in the ActiveSheet. If you have `N` charts, delete all of them but one, it would refer to it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But it does not work. Still shows error in that line and in subsequent lines.