# Prevent overlapping of data labels in pie chart

Tags: excel

I understand that when the value for one slice of a pie chart is too small, there is bound to have overlap.

However, the client insisted on a pie chart with data labels beside each slice (without legends as well) so I'm not sure what other solutions is there to "prevent overlap". Manually moving the labels wouldn't work as the values in the chart are dynamic.

[image]

Comment: You may be able to start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773137)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Best Fit` option under `Format Data Labels -> Label Options`
Image attached.[image]

Comment: I tried this method, but client doesn't like the labels to be inside the chart