# How to automatically align data labels in graph when greater than the other?

Tags: excel, graph, label, alignment

I have the following graph in excel. My question is how can I automatically get the data labels of greater numbers ABOVE and the less numbers UNDER the line so they won't collide like on day 24.

Thank you in advance for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yseik.png)

Is there any style or settings which can solve my problem, so I don't have to manually change each's values position when crossing each other?

[Unfortunately, the greater number is still below the line and the less number is above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTxy.png)

Comment: Seems like days 2-6 have overlap as well, do you want that to be different too?

Comment: Yes. The above mentioned should be true for each data label.

Comment: Have you tried the first two steps in: https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-chart-data-labels-overlap/  ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Thank you! I updated my post with another picture. You can see, still I have the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Andy Pope mentions using 3 additional data series that only display the data labels for above/right or below but I'm not sure myself how that'd be done https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/1062385-data-labels-positions-automatically-update-on-chart-to-avoid-overlap.html or perhaps if you're a bit familiar with VBA, you can tinker with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770429/excel-macro-to-fix-overlapping-data-labels-in-line-chart

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5896-excel-chart-add-data-labels-from-different-column.html this one solved my problem, thank you for helping me!